# Print button to specific printer [HTML / PHP]

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, printing

I'd like to know if it is possible via PHP to setup a print button which will print to a specified printer which is not the default printer.

Basically, I have 2 print layouts, one A4 and the other one an 80mm (receipt). Right now every time I click on the print button, it will show a dialog box and I have to choose the printer, I was wondering if I can do something faster, which when I click on button "Print A4", it will print on the A4 printer and when I click on the button "Print Receipt", it will print on the receipt printer.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible since PHP is server sided.

Furthermore, the OS Print options cannot be bypassed by a website. The Default printer is determined on the visitor's OS. This is among other things in place to safeguard the printer from malicious printing by websites.

Comment: I thought so, but decided to ask anyway. thank you @PaulS

Comment: @Bertu No Problem! You can accept as answer by clicking on the tick on the left.

Answer (score 0):

Look here,

WebApp Hardware Bridge (succeeder of "Chrome Hardware Bridge / Chrome Direct Print")

Make it possible for WebApp to perform silent print and access to serial ports.

Common use cases:

Web-based POS - PDF and ESC/POS receipt silent print
Web-based WMS - Serial weight scale real-time reading, delivery Note/packing List silent print
WebApp that need to read/write to serial ports

https://github.com/imTigger/webapp-hardware-bridge